# localization and optional parameters laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Is it possible to put an optional parameter before a required one?

I am trying to create a multilingual web application using laravel 5, if the user didnt specify the language in URL, the default language is used:

`http://localhost/localizationtest/public/es/test/4`

how can i make this URL works: `http://localhost/localizationtest/public/test/4`

my routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{lang?}/test'), function($lang = null)
    {

        Route::get('{id}', function($lang = null, $id) {

            App::setlocale($lang);

            return view('lang_test')->with('id', $id);


        });

    });
```

one more question: is it possible to put the id this way: /test4 instead of /test/4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare an explicit route for it?

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', function($id) {
       App::setlocale('es');
       return view('lang_test')->with('id', $id);
});
```

To answer your other question - yes you can change the wildcard so that its that way. (remove the '/').